# How did Arkarian maintenance crew get to the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

In the beginning of "[Starship Mine](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starship_Mine_(episode))" episode (Star Trek Next Generation 6x18) maintenance crew boards Enterprise-D to install field diverters in key ship's areas. They start with the bridge.

How did they get to the bridge? Are there any other doors, except turbolift and captain's ready room, in the right wall in bridge (looking from screen perspective)?

I watched this scene twice and either I'm blind or they enters bridge from... captain's ready room.

Comment: There are three turbolifts...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three turbolifts to the bridge.  One behind the captain's chair to its left (screen right), two in front of the captain's chair to the left and right.  In the episode, the turbolift to the captain's right is used.

[image]

The close doors in this image lead to the third turbolift and the [head](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bathroom).  The top left door leads to the observation lounge.  Also note, this image is Generations era, so additional bridge stations were installed.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. To clarify. Where exactly (when looking for a position of person sitting in captain's chair) is then an entrace to captain's Ready Room?

Comment: @trejder Its to the front left, left of the front left turbolift

Comment: @trejder: It's the visible door on the far right. (The door to the adjacent turbolift is obscured.)